# Understating of Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $K=\{h\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}: h \ is\  injective\}$ be a set.

Prove/disprove that $K\sim \mathbb{N}$.

I think that this theorem is false. I want to disprove it by Cantor's diagonal argument but don't know how to do so.

Comment: Hint: can you find an injective map $2^{\mathbb{N}}\to K$?

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed do this with Cantor's diagonal argument.

Here is a hint: Every strictly increasing function is injective. Given a list of injective functions, can you define a strictly increasing function that is different from the $k$-th function at position $k$?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @WardBeullens answer...

Suppose there is countably many injective functions: $(f_n), f_n:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N $. Now, define $f (n) $ inductively:

- $f (1)=f_1 (1)+1$
- $f (n+1)=\max(f (n), f_n (n))+1$

That way, $f $ is strictly increasing (hence injective) and $f (n)\ne f_n (n) $ for every $n\in\mathbb N $.

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove this by reducing it to a fact you already know.

Cantor's diagonal argument shows that the set of infinite binary sequences is uncountable. So if we can find a way to turn an infinite binary sequence into an injective function on the natural numbers - and do this in a way where no two sequences get turned into the same function - we'll have shown that $K$ is *at least as large as* the set of infinite binary sequences, and hence uncountable.

There are several ways to do this. Basically, you want to find two "options" for the behavior of a function on a given input; given a sequence of $0$s and $1$s, you'll let this sequence "choose" amongst these options.

For example, here's one approach which **doesn't work** for this problem. My two options, given a number $n$ as input, are:

- *Option $0$*: Map $n$ to $3$.
- *Option $1$*: Map $n$ to $17$.

This does give me a way to turn an infinite binary sequence into a function on naturals. For example, the sequence $010101...$ turns into the function which sends $0, 2, 4, ...$ to $3$ and $1, 3, 5, ...$ to $17$. However, obviously this doesn't produce *injective* functions, so this isn't helpful.

If you can find some way of tweaking this approach so that the result is always injective, and so that no two sequences get turned into the same function, then you'll have solved the problem.

---

Let me give one final hint: *make the options depend on $n$*. For example:

- *Option $0$*: Map $n$ to $n^2$.
- *Option $1$*: Map $n$ to $n^3$.

This *still* doesn't quite work - think about the fact that $8^2=4^3$ - but it points in the right direction; you need to find something like this that actually guarantees injectivity.